# keyboard_teleop

Tags: ros, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hola
Can someone explain me this code?:

def getKey():

```
tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())

select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)

key = sys.stdin.read(1)

termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, settings)

return key
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45934/keyboard_teleop/) by [andreapatri](https://answers.ros.org/users/1713/andreapatri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't really ROS specific code -- basically, it is accessing the keyboard (stdin) using standard Python methods to get one keypress at a time. See http://docs.python.org/library/termios.html

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3